# Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 (php)

Tags: php, laravel, ini

I keep on getting this error "**Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0  Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\file\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0**" after I run the project, though I have tried and follow some solutions from the net like in the php.ini "include_path=" to be specific but it didn't work. And btw, I don't have anti-virus software in my pc. Can someone help me how to fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**your server.php file is missing.**

*just create a file named server.php at the root directory of your laravel project and paste the following code:*

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

**OR**

*Change `debug=false` to `debug=true` in your `.env` file or You need to edit the `config/app.php` file and change the `debug = false` to `debug = true`.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try bringing back the lines 24 and 25 to live in the phpunit.xml file of your project, in case you are using Laravel.

```
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

By default they are commented so if you uncomment them it should work.